# Cannot create temporary file at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/RRDTool/OO.pm

Tags: perl, net-snmp, rrdtool

I was trying to create RRD database for SNMP queries and as code shown below...

Code :

```
# Constructor     
my $rrd = RRDTool::OO->new(file => "myrrdfile.rrd" );

# Create a round-robin database # one-second intervals
$rrd->create(
     step        => 1,
     data_source => { name      => "devicebatterylevel",
                      type      => "GAUGE" },
     archive     => { rows      => 1 });

$rrd->update($Batterylevel);
```

Output:

```
ERROR: rrdtool create myrrdfile.rrd --step 1 DS:mydatasource:GAUGE:2:U:U RRA:MAX:0.5:1:5 failed:
Cannot create temporary file at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/RRDTool/OO.pm line 444
```

(Line break added for readability.)

Please guide me further.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have write permission to the current directory.  Are you calling this script directly from the commandline, or from another application?  If so, verify that the current working directory really is what you think it is.  Also, check that your /tmp is not 100% full (unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

I got the solution, the mistake is i didn't give wright access to file.
Now it's clear and script is working well.

Thanks and Regards,
Nayana